# Tryton as a CalDAV server

Tags: python, thunderbird, caldav, tryton

What is the performance of Tryton as a CalDAV server? How does it perform with Mozilla Sunbird / Thunderbird-lighting as a client? Is it ready to apply in real business environments? If not, what other solutions would you recommend?

Answer (score -1):

The Tryton CalDAV server is based on [pywebdav](https://code.google.com/p/pywebdav/). It conforms to the specification and works with many clients.
([an incomplete list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmlePWQYEUqZdGNQMzdtM3d4VUFVQ19weGN0MnhZcVE&hl=en_US#gid=0))